# Convert tweets into Bson using twitteR and rmongo library

Tags: json, r, mongodb

Since the streamR connection API doesn't work anymore on Tweeter I try to convert the output from searchTwitter function (from TwitteR) into BSON before insert it in a mongodb database.

```
test.tweets = searchTwitter("mongodb", n=10, lang="en")
class(test.tweets)
test.text=laply(test.tweets,function(t) t$getText())
class(toJSON(test.text))
bson <- mongo.bson.from.JSON(test.text)
```

R return an error : "Error in mongo.bson.from.JSON(test.text) : Not a valid JSON content:..."
How to resolve this conversion or does exist another solution ?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
library(rmongodb)
library(jsonlite)
test.text <- c("A tweet", "Another tweet")
(bson <- mongo.bson.from.JSON(toJSON(test.text)))
# 1 : 2      A tweet
# 2 : 2      Another tweet
```